# Register WP users with the same username and email address

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have added the code below into function.php but it didn't work:

```
function create_new_user_login_change($user_id) {
    $new_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $my_email = $new_user->user_email;
    wp_update_user(array('ID' => $user_id, 'user_login' => $my_email));
}

add_action('user_register', 'create_new_user_login_change');
```

At least I want users to register with the same email address.

What the solution?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user to add a user, but I am not sure of your question. What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Any error messages?

Comment: I have added myself as a user. Automatically I am a customer in WordPress. However, I now want to become a subscriber therefore, I need to register again. When I try to register again, it says username and email already exist. I would like myself as well as other customer on the database to register again with the same details, username and email address. I do not want to manually remove the email address in the database therefore I need a function where the username and email address can overwrite.

Comment: Seems to me you should not be using the 'wp_update_user' at all, rather just have a form with a custom field such as 'is_subscriber' on a custom form. You can use a plugin for this, of which there are a few. Either use Google to find one, or try 'https://subscribe2.wordpress.com/'